# Audio with data URI fails in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, mp3

I have the following html. This runs in Firefox, but in chrome the element isn't playable. Why?

```html
<audio controls src="data:binary/octet-stream;base64,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"></audio>
```

Here's the code I'm using to generate the src above.

```js
export const downloadFile = async (fileName: string, config: ApiConfig) => {
  const response = await request(`/media/${fileName}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { ...getAuthHeaders(config) },
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("API Download failed.", { cause: response });
  }

  const blob = await response.blob();
  const reader = new FileReader();

  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(reader.result as string);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correct content type/MIME type.

Currently you have `binary/octet-stream`.  If it's MP3, it should be `audio/mpeg`.

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,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"></audio>
```

Also, I generally recommend against using data URIs and base64 encoding.  You're adding 33% overhead to the overall size, not to mention a lot of memory and CPU.  While this trivial 1-second audio example isn't that big of a problem, longer clips can be.  Very rarely is this actually needed.  You can usually load a Blob with [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static).

Comment: Changing the mimetype worked. Thanks. The data is fetched from a private api, and I've been struggling to figure out how to setup a src for an api that isn't public. I ended up making the authenticated request and generating the data URI. I'd love to hear of better ways though.

Comment: Added some context code to my original question.

Comment: I changed over to using createObjectURL, though I'm not convinced it's not dark magic.

Comment: Is there any way you can put your auth in the URL itself, like in the query string?  If so, you could just pass this URL directly to the audio element and skip all this.  That'd be more performant, as it'd stream.  If you wanted to stream without that, MediaSource is a possibility but is a real hassle to get working and it doesn't work with all the media types that the element can play.  Aside from those two options, the blob URL is the way to go.  A fourth option is to use a ServiceWorker to append the auth headers to the request, but there are instances where ServiceWorkers are disabled.

Comment: A query string could be an option. I'm using Amazon API Gateway. I know I can do it with other services directly but would prefer to go through that.